# Floating div not visible above an applet inside iframe in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, iframe, applet

I am loading an external page that has an applet in an iframe. And I need to display a floating div above this iframe. If I use position relative or absolute on the containing divs and a higher z-index on the floating div it works fine in firefox but does not work in Chrome or IE. Both chrome and IE renders the floating div below the applet.

Any pointers for this?

If I use some page the does not have an applet in the iframe then it works fine.
I went thru similar issues and looks like if I put my div in the same level as applet and give higher z-index it works but that is an external page that I load and I cant put anything in there.

I have code somewhat like this:

```
<div id="div1" style="position: absolute; z-index:1;">
     <iframe src="http://xyz...." width="400" height="200" ></iframe>
</div>
<div id="div2" style="position: absolute; top:20; z-index:5">
    Floating div content
</div>
```

Comment: This is a long standing problem to which I have never seen a solution.  Applets do not 'float' well amongst layered HTML elements.  There is generally no away of altering how the browser will render them when applets are in the mix.

Comment: Have you tried the opacity: 99 hack?

Answer (score 0):

First, Please note these points..

1. The `<applet>` tag is not supported in HTML5. Use the `<object>` tag instead.
2. The `<applet>` element is deprecated in HTML 4.01.

Then, Please make sure the java plugin (JRE) is up to date for the browser.
Chrome browser recently is supporting the applet tag. Prior, it used not to support the applet tag.